# Manipulating Data in Vue for Chart Options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

I am hitting a rest api giving me a dataset on a piece of equipment.  I need to get the first column of datas as an array and I seem to not get it right.  I have tried computed and methods in vue but it always returns [].  Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? {{datas}} prints out my JSON with no issues but when i add {{ getDate }} it returns can't  find date of undefined.

Thanks

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <!-- <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="datas" class="elevation-1">
        <template slot="items" scope="props">
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{props.item.date}}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{props.item.iron}}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{props.item.chromium}}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{props.item.lead}}</td>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>-->
    <p>{{ datas }}</p>
    <!-- <p v-for="data in datas">{{ data.date }}</p> -->
    {{ getDates }}
    <center>
      <chart :options="chartOptionsBar"></chart>
    </center>
    <chart :options="chartOptionsLine"></chart>
    <p>108J View</p>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "E108J",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      datas: [],
      chartDates: [],
      chartOptionsLine: {
        xAxis: {
          data: ["q", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: "value"
        },
        series: [
          {
            type: "line",
            data: [63, 75, 24, 92]
          }
        ],
        title: {
          text: "Quarterly Sales Results",
          x: "center",
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 24
          }
        },
        color: ["#127ac2"]
      },
      chartOptionsBar: {
        xAxis: {
          data: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: "value"
        },
        series: [
          {
            type: "bar",

            data: [63, 75, 24, 92]
          }
        ],
        title: {
          text: "Quarterly Sales Results",
          x: "center",
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 36
          }
        }
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/E108J")
      .then(response => (this.datas = response.data));
  },
  computed: {
    getDates() {
      let chartdates;
      for (let i = 0;i< this.datas.length; i++) {
        chartdates = this.data[i];
      }
      return chartdates;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

JSON Data:

```
[
{
date: "10/18/2018",
iron: "0",
chromium: "0",
lead: "3",
copper: "0",
tin: "0",
aluminum: "0",
nickel: "0",
silver: "0",
silicon: "1",
boron: "0",
sodium: "0",
magnesium: "0",
calcium: "1",
barioum: "0",
phosphorous: "3",
zinc: "2",
molybden: "1",
tin1: "0",
vandium: "2",
w: "1",
potassium: "0",
antimony: "0",
lithium: "0",
maganese: "0",
cadmium: "",
visc40: "214.41",
tan: "0.32",
kfish: "22",
water: "0.0022",
pc0: "455",
pc1: "139",
pc2: "25",
pc3: "11",
pc4: "1",
pc5: "0",
pciso0: "16",
pciso1: "14",
pciso2: "12"
},
{
date: "11/2/2018",
iron: "0",
chromium: "0",
lead: "2",
copper: "0",
tin: "3",
aluminum: "0",
nickel: "1",
silver: "0",
silicon: "1",
boron: "0",
sodium: "0",
magnesium: "0",
calcium: "0",
barioum: "0",
phosphorous: "10",
zinc: "0",
molybden: "0",
tin1: "0",
vandium: "0",
w: "0",
potassium: "0",
antimony: "7",
lithium: "0",
maganese: "0",
cadmium: "",
visc40: "213.56",
tan: "0.19",
kfish: "29",
water: "0.0029",
pc0: "339",
pc1: "39",
pc2: "21",
pc3: "8",
pc4: "0",
pc5: "0",
pciso0: "16",
pciso1: "12",
pciso2: "12"
},
{
date: "11/29/2018",
iron: "0",
chromium: "0",
lead: "0",
copper: "0",
tin: "0",
aluminum: "0",
nickel: "0",
silver: "0",
silicon: "2",
boron: "0",
sodium: "0",
magnesium: "0",
calcium: "0",
barioum: "0",
phosphorous: "1",
zinc: "1",
molybden: "0",
tin1: "0",
vandium: "0",
w: "1",
potassium: "0",
antimony: "0",
lithium: "0",
maganese: "0",
cadmium: "",
visc40: "217.67",
tan: "0.18",
kfish: "21",
water: "0.0021",
pc0: "921",
pc1: "223",
pc2: "40",
pc3: "18",
pc4: "1",
pc5: "0",
pciso0: "17",
pciso1: "15",
pciso2: "12"
},
{
date: "12/13/2018",
iron: "0",
chromium: "0",
lead: "1",
copper: "0",
tin: "0",
aluminum: "1",
nickel: "0",
silver: "0",
silicon: "0",
boron: "0",
sodium: "0",
magnesium: "0",
calcium: "0",
barioum: "0",
phosphorous: "2",
zinc: "0",
molybden: "2",
tin1: "0",
vandium: "0",
w: "1",
potassium: "0",
antimony: "0",
lithium: "0",
maganese: "0",
cadmium: "",
visc40: "214.46",
tan: "0.26",
kfish: "22",
water: "0.0022",
pc0: "581",
pc1: "101",
pc2: "39",
pc3: "24",
pc4: "7",
pc5: "4",
pciso0: "16",
pciso1: "14",
pciso2: "12"
},
{
date: "1/14/2019",
iron: "0",
chromium: "0",
lead: "0",
copper: "0",
tin: "0",
aluminum: "0",
nickel: "1",
silver: "0",
silicon: "1",
boron: "0",
sodium: "0",
magnesium: "0",
calcium: "0",
barioum: "0",
phosphorous: "4",
zinc: "0",
molybden: "0",
tin1: "0",
vandium: "0",
w: "0",
potassium: "0",
antimony: "0",
lithium: "0",
maganese: "0",
cadmium: "",
visc40: "222.35",
tan: "0.29",
kfish: "13",
water: "0.0013",
pc0: "663",
pc1: "140",
pc2: "13",
pc3: "11",
pc4: "2",
pc5: "0",
pciso0: "17",
pciso1: "14",
pciso2: "11"
}
]
```

Comment: in `getDates` you're not creating an array.  You're just continously setting `chartdates` to the value at `i`.

Comment: It sounds like the line inside the for loop should be  `chartdates[i] = this.datas[i][0]`

Comment: @Josef7 I tried your  suggestion and i get the following error:  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: What is the structure of `datas`?

Comment: @Josef7 Ihave added the json data i;m getting to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to be safe, check that `datas` exists in your computed property. It is set to an array initially, but if invalid data comes back it could cause an error. So you could check something right inside your computed property like `if(this.datas && this.datas.length)`, and only if that is true try to fill in `chartdates`. Otherwise, return an empty array.

Second, based on the JSON you included, the date can be extracted in the for loop using

```
this.datas[i].date
```

What you have now would get the whole object inside `{ .. }` instead of just the date. There's also a typo using `this.data[i]` when it should be `this.datas[i]`.

Finally, to make `chartdates` an array you need to set `chartdates[i]` to each *i*th value, otherwise only the last value will be stored in chartdates as Steven pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div v-if="datas.length > 0">
<p>{{ datas }}</p>
 {{ getDates }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this lines of code

```
getDates() {
  let chartdates;
  for (let i = 0;i< this.datas.length; i++) {
    chartdates = this.data[i];
  }
  return chartdates;
}
```

may be `this.data[i]` is replace by `this.datas[i];`